# How do I use my LSTM output as input for another LSTM in keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

In a sentence, I want to predict five different binary values. For each binary value, I want to predict a one-hot encoded value.

To do so I programmed 2 different LSTMs. But now I am not sure how I could use the output of the first LSTM to use it correctly in my second LSTM. So first, my two models:

#### First model

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(word_count, embedding_size, input_length = sentence_length))
model.add(LSTM(hidden_layer_units))
model.add(Dense(5))
model.add(Activation("sigmoid"))
```

The output can be 0 or 1 for 5 values. F.e. [0,1,0,0,1]

#### Second model

```
main_input = Input(shape = (sentence_length,), dtype = 'int32', name = 'main_input')
embedding = Embedding(word_count, embedding_size,
                    input_length=sentence_length)(main_input)
lstm_out = LSTM(hidden_layer_units)(embedding)

auxiliary_input = Input(shape=(5,), name='aux_input')
x = concatenate([lstm_out, auxiliary_input])
main_output = Dense(4, activation='sigmoid', name='main_output')(x)

model = Model(inputs=[main_input, auxiliary_input], outputs=main_output)
```

The input of my auxiliary_input is like [0,0,0,1,0].
The output is one-hot encoded [0,0,1,0]

#### My idea

I first thought that maybe I can use the output of my first model directly as input for my second model. The problem: THe output of my secon model would change and I do not know how it is possible to have a output layer for my second model that can predict a 2-dimensional output like

```
[
 [0,0,0,1]
 [0,0,1,0]
 [0,0,0,1]
 [0,0,0,1]
 [1,0,0,0]
]
```

So my question:

1. Is it possible to use the data of the first model directly as input for the second model by having an 2-dimensional output layer?

   or 2. Is the following possible: For each binary value of my first model I pass a one-hot encoded array as input to the second model. So the second model exists 5 times. Only if all 5 second models predict the output correct my complete model is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I reshaped my output layer and evaluated that reshaped layer. SO my last two layers look like this:

```
main_output = Dense(20,activation='sigmoid')(concatenated_layer)
reshaped_out = Reshape(target_shape=(5,4))(main_output)
```